# executeAsync not passing return value to callback

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

I'm using intern JS/leadfood testing framework. I'm using **executeAsync**. I expect the return value from executeAsync to be passed to the callback to executeAsync, but this is not happening. Should the following work?

```
return  this.remote.get(require.toUrl(url));
    //do stuff
    .executeAsync(function (done) {

        require([<library>],
            function ([<function>]) {
                return <function which returns Promise>
                .then(function (value) {
                    return <function which returns Promise>
                ...
                }).then(function () {
                    done(window.location);

                })
            })

    })
    .then(function (loc) {
        console.log(loc);
    })
```

Execution gets to the last callback in executeAsync successfully. The callback to executeAsync is called successfully. But the value passed to the executeAsync callback is `undefined`.

**Edit:** 
I have found out that even if you set a executeAsync timeout of a very large number, this timeout will be ignored if you do not call `this.async(timeout)` specifying the correct timeout (default is 30 seconds at time of writing). So the issue was that the test was taking longer than 30 seconds and the value passed to done was not making it to the callback to executeAsync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeAsync` uses a callback to determine when its function has finished running. This callback is automatically passed as the last argument (the only argument if you're not passing anything else) to the `executeAsync` function:

```
define([
    'require',
    'intern!object'
], function (
    require,
    registerSuite
) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'test',

        foo: function () {
            return this.remote.get(require.toUrl('./index.html'))
                .setExecuteAsyncTimeout(5000)
                .executeAsync(function (done) {
                    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            resolve();
                        }, 1000);
                    });

                    promise.then(function () {
                        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                resolve();
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    }).then(function () {
                        done(window.location);
                    });
                })
                .then(function (loc) {
                    // This prints out a full location object from the
                    // browser.
                    console.log(loc);
                }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I implemented it as you have the code here, but `value` for me is still `undefined`. What is `done`?

Comment: As I said, the `executeAsync` function is automatically passed a callback as its last argument. This callback, which you can call whatever you want (I generally call it 'done'), should be called by your `executeAsync` function when it's finished with whatever it's doing. You can't return a promise from an `executeAsync` function (well, you can, but Intern won't pay attention to it). The `executeAsync` function is going to run in the browser, where promises might not be available, so Intern uses a callback rather than a promise to get its return value.

Comment: So after passing in a function called `done` to the `script` parameter passed to `executeAsync`, and then calling `done` as the last step in `executeAsync` to signal that it has finished executing, I would expect the value passed to the callback to `executeAsync` (`value` in this case) to be the value passed to `done`. But `value` is still `undefined`.

Comment: I updated my example to be more complete. This code works as-is (assuming you have an `index.html` page the the same location as the test file).

Comment: A difference between your answer and my code is that I am chaining Promises by returning them at each callback. Finally in the last callback in `executeAsync` I am calling `done`. Should the fact that I am chaining promises by returning them in each callback in `executeAsync` matter? I am calling `done` just like you are in your answer, however the value passed to the callback to `executeAsync` is undefined. Additionally, the test is timing out.

Comment: I've edited the code in my question to be more complete. As you can see it is a little different than the answer you gave. But in my case `loc` is undefined. Whereas in your answer, `loc` has a value.

Comment: This answer is only correct when Deferreds are not chained inside executeAsync.

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between using a setTimeout or using promises in this case. If the `done` method is called with a value, `executeAsync` will resolve with that value (as long as it's something that can be serialized). I've updated my example to use Promises rather than just a bare setTimeout, and that works fine. The fact that your test is timing out suggests that the `then` method in your Promise chain isn't being called, which would indicate that something further up the chain threw an error. Try also calling done in a `catch` block, just to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112723/discussion-between-cosmos1990-and-jason0x43).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Leadfoot documents here

https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#executeAsync

> Returns
>
> The value returned by the remote code. Only values that can be serialised to JSON, plus DOM elements, can be returned.

What are you returning from the executed function?

Comment: I'm returning an array, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @cosmos1990 you sure? it looks like you may actually be returning a promise, that eventually resolves to an array. definitely not the same thing.

Comment: That may be. In any case, I'm now passing in a callback function and calling it, instead of returning a value, as @jason0x43 has suggested.